# VSCode doesn't show password dialog for GitHub authentication

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I tried to push from VSCode(origin is on GitHub), and VSCode asked me an username.

However, it didn't ask me a password. Instead, it just closed the thing and displayed the dialog "Git: Missing or invalid credentials." Here's the log.

```
Missing or invalid credentials.
Wrong number of arguments
remote: Invalid username or password.
```

Normal `git push` command through Terminal works without any problem.

Comment: Please provide the complete scenario. Are you using any particular extension? Are you using SSH key based authentication or HTTPS for the remote?

Comment: @hrmnjt I just "git clone"d the repository, so if I'm right it's HTTPS based connection. I am using GitLens but I don't think that's the problem as the problem still occurred after disabling the extension.

Comment: Can you push from the command line?

Comment: @rioV8 Yeah, as I wrote at the last line.

Comment: Are you on Mac because you use `Terminal`? It could be different on Linux/Windows/Mac.

Comment: @rioV8 I'm on KDE Neon and using Konsole and oh-my-zsh. Didn't intend to point that "Terminal."

Comment: Are you able to change your remote's URL to use SSH instead of HTTPS? Using an SSH key, VSCode won't need to get the password from you–either you'll create the key with no password (which I recommend) or the git installation on your computer will include a dialog that gets the password from you.

Comment: I changed to SSH, and it works. However, while it works well and it's enough for now, I don't want to use this method if I can use HTTPS without any problem. Anyway, thanks for the help!

Comment: It is safer to use SSH. HTTPS should be a temporary approach

Comment: To check the SSH or HTTPS you can run `git remote -v` . That lists down the remotes with the authentication mechanism